# Enabling and disabling a Text based on checkbox and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML code i have around 56 check boxes.
If I select one check box I want another text box to be enabled. ie when no of check boxes selected is one.

But if the no of check boxes selected exceeds 1 , greater that one I want that text box to be disabled

My code :

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="template" value="SOL42_Template-BBRY">BBRY<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="template" value="SOL42_Template-GPRS">GPRS<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="template" value="SOL42_Template-MMS-PXT01">MMS-PXT01<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="template" value="SOL42_Template-MMS-PXT02">MMS-PXT02<br>

<input type="text" name="SecondarytextBox" id="SecondarytextBox">
```

Now when any one of the check box is selected the secondary textbox should be enabled or visible, if more than one check box is selected the secondary text box shld be disabled or invisible.

Comment: Have you any code that you have tried?

Comment: what was wrong in the question ?? and why is it down voted ??

Comment: Just because I did not know how to do I have posted it here. I guess one cant master all type of languages front end db or middle ware.. just because u ppl have the privilege to down vote just dont do it. may be this would be an easy question for u, who knows u might struggle in a different tech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('[name=template]').change(function(){
   $('#SecondarytextBox').toggle($('[name=template]:checked').length==1);
}).eq(0).change();
```

**### Working Demo**

Comment: It makes the part to disappear, but does not disable. In the servlet i am able to retrieve values of it. If disabled it ll not send values

Comment: for disabling you need to add attribute disabled to element ` $('#SecondarytextBox')`

Comment: Is it possible to reset ? I mean when one check box is ticked that second box is visible and I can enter the value, but when I Uncheck and check it gain I am able to see the value entered. When uncheck or more than one is checked the value should be reset . is it possible ??

Comment: set the val in change event to empty `$('#SecondarytextBox').val('')`.like this http://jsfiddle.net/kz89g3ek/